# Make Grunt Server available through IP Address

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm currently testing my web server through Grunt running it with the command "grunt serve" ever time. It's great for local testing because all I have to do is save a file and the changes are uploaded automatically. However, I was wondering whether or not it was possible to configure my Grunt server along with port-forwarding my ip address so people could connect to my website using the ip of the machine running the Grunt server.

All of the examples I've found for this seem to be of people wanting to create a server where they locally connect other devices to through IPv4, but I need to connect a machine that is not local.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the server plugins in grunt have a configuration in `Gruntfile.js`. The grunt plugin configuration for the server has mostly a `host` option which is set to `127.0.0.1`. change it to `0.0.0.0`makes the app available on all ip's assigned to the machine.